# integrate Mule IDE in the Eclipse neon

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, mule

I tried to integrate Mule IDE with the Eclipse neon, I follow this:
https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-studio/v/5/studio-in-eclipse

But the link http://studio.mulesoft.org/r4/plugin don't work.

**This is the error message:**

```
Unable to read repository at dist.muleforge.org/muleide/updates/3.4/content.xml. Socket operation on nonsocket: configureBlocking
```

How to solve this issue??

Comment: What do you mean it "don't work"? Are you getting errors? What are you expecting to happen and what is actually happening?

Comment: Did you "upgrade" to neon, or download a fresh installation?

Comment: @Mooz My Neon is fresh installation, also always I got error msg, telling me that this repository is not available

Comment: @Mooz This is the error message: Unable to read repository at http://dist.muleforge.org/muleide/updates/3.4/content.xml.
Unable to read repository at http://dist.muleforge.org/muleide/updates/3.4/content.xml.
Socket operation on nonsocket: configureBlocking

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to install this while over VPN? If so, disconnect from the VPN and try again.